# How to make xsd files available for a web service client?

Tags: java, jax-ws, java-6

I'm developing a new web service at my company. We have a POJO application server communicating with the wxternal clients through CORBA and RMI. Just to make things easier for myself I decided to test a possibility to expose the web service without a servlet container.

Here's the essential code

```
public class  ServiceLauncher {
    private Endpoint endpoint;

    public ServiceLauncher(){
        endpoint = Endpoint.create(new ServiceServer());
        endpoint.publish("http://0.0.0.0:1234/Service");
    }
}
```

Connecting to http://`localhost`:1234/Service?wsdl works fine. Web Service works also. However, testing it through soapUI fails due to unavailable schemas at certain addresses imported in the wsdl file. The error I face is

404 Not Found
No context found for request

Is there a way to make those xsd files accessible to clients?

Comment: Not sure if this would affect anything, but could you try to publish using 127.0.0.1?,

`endpoint.publish("http://127.0.0.1:1234/Service");`

Comment: Changing the address to 127.0.0.1 didn't help. Probably, another side effect of thе problem is that @SchemaValidation annotation on the WebService class is not working. Running the service on the tomcat looks fine and validation is enabled. I basically have 2 options: stick to the plan of using built-in jvm deployment resolving, hopefully the described issue and enjoying the ease of reusing a lot of available code, or deploying to tomcat and figuring out how to pass the messages between app server and the container and back. I prefer the first one (spare you details)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a big mistake on my part. I was too much focused on how files reside in the project and how they are accessible within an already implemented service (we're making a copy of something existing) that I completely overlooked the generated wsdl (i've seen too much of it lately). All xsd files **are accessible** but with different url.

I was expecting (tested on the existing service) something like `http://foo:1234/xsd/Entity.xsd`
instead I got `http://foo:1234/Service?xsd=1`